# Scan a sentence with space into *char array in C

Tags: c

I'm not good at using C language. Here is my dumb question. Now I am trying to get input from users, which may have spaces. And what I need to do is to split this sentence using space as delimiter and then put each fragment into char* array. 
Ex:
Assuming I have `char* result[10];`, and the input is: `Good morning John`. The output should be `result[0]="Good";` `result[1]="morning";` `result[2]="John";`
I have already tried `scanf("%[^\n]",input);` and `gets(input);` Yet it is still hard to deal with String in C. And also I have tried `strtok`, but it seems that it only replaced the space by `NULL`. Hence the result will be `GoodNULLmorningNULLJohn`. Obviously it's not what I want. Please help my dumb question. Thanks.
**Edit:**
This is what I don't understand when using `strtok`. Here is a test code.
The `substr` still displayed `Hello there`. It seems `subtok` only replace a `null` at the space position. Thus, I can't use the `substr` in an `if` statement.

```
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    char* substr;
    char str[] = "Hello there";
    substr = strtok(str," ");

    if(substr=="Hello"){
        printf("YES!!!!!!!!!!");
    }

    printf("%s\n",substr);

    for(i=0;i<11;i++){
        printf("%c", substr[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I you really don't want strtok like Alter Mann show (i think strtok, maybe with strdup, is the best), you still can make your own function like [this](https://github.com/sebastiencs/my_ftp/blob/master/src/client/my_str_to_wordtab.c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As most of the other answers haven't covered another thing you were asking:

`strtok` will not allocate temporary memory and will use your given string to replace every separator with a zero termination. This is why `Good morning John` becomes `GoodNULLmorningNULLJohn`. If it wouldn't do this, each token would print the whole rest of the string on its tail like:

```
result[0] = Good morning John
result[1] = morning John
result[2] = John
```

So if you want to keep your original input and an array of char* per word, you need 2 buffers. There is no other way around that. You also need the token buffer to stay in scope as long as you use the result array of char* pointers, else that one points to invalid memory and will cause undefined behavior.

So this would be a possible solution:

```
int main()
{
    const unsigned int resultLength = 10;
    char* result[resultLength];
    memset(result, 0, sizeof result);   // we should also zero the result array to avoid access violations later on

    // Read the input from the console
    char input[256];
    fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);

    // Get rid of the newline char
    input[strlen(input) - 1] = 0;

    // Copy the input string to another buffer for your tokens to work as expected
    char tokenBuffer[256];
    strcpy(tokenBuffer, input);

    // Setting of the pointers per word
    char* token = strtok(tokenBuffer, " ");
    for (unsigned int i = 0; token != NULL && i < resultLength; i++)
    {
        result[i] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    // Print the result
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < resultLength; i++)
    {
        printf("result[%d] = %s\n", i, result[i] != NULL ? result[i] : "NULL");
    }
    printf("The input is: %s\n", input);

    return 0;
}
```

It prints:

```
result[0] = Good
result[1] = morning
result[2] = John
result[3] = NULL
result[4] = NULL
result[5] = NULL
result[6] = NULL
result[7] = NULL
result[8] = NULL
result[9] = NULL
The input is: Good morning John
```

Answer (score 4):

Never use `gets`, is deprecated in C99 and removed from C11.

IMO, `scanf` is not a good function to use when you don't know the number of elements before-hand, I suggest `fgets`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[128];
    char *ptr;

    fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);
    /* Remove trailing newline */
    ptr = strchr(str, '\n');
    if (ptr != NULL) {
        *ptr = '\0';
    }
    /* Tokens */
    ptr = strtok(str, " ");
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", ptr);
        ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a shame that `fgets` doesn't return the number of characters read, but there you go.  You do only need to test `str[strlen(str)-1]` for newline, though - it can't be anywhere else in the buffer.

Comment: @TobySpeight, thanks for your suggestion but I prefer `strchr`, in this case `strlen(str)` is > 0 because of the trailing newline, but an empty string could crash on strlen - 1

Comment: @Toby Speight  `str[strlen(str)-1]` is code exploitable by hackers.  `fgets()` will easily read a _line_ that begins with the null character.  Before attempting `str[strlen(str)-1]`, code needs to insure the initial character is not the null character.

Answer (score 1):

`gets` is not recommended to use, as there is no way to tell the size of the buffer. `fgets` is ok here because it will stop reading when the 1st new line is encountered. You could use strtok to store all the splited words in to an array of strings, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char s[256];
    char *result[10];

    fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);
    char *p = strtok(s, " \n");
    int cnt = 0;
    while (cnt < (sizeof result / sizeof result[0]) && p) {
        result[cnt++] = p;
        p = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        printf("%s\n", result[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should change `while (p)` to `while (cnt <= 9 && p)` to prevent an overflow. Also, you forgot to get rid of the newline character that `fgets` consumes.

Comment: @CoolGuy Thanks, fixed.